# fullcalendar external event data unwantedly being converted from string to number at eventReceive:

Tags: type-conversion, fullcalendar

I am passing data - from an external event div - to a fullcalendar:

```
<div 
class="fc-event"
data-some_text="name_of_Some_event_221"
data-some_ID_number_as_string="45787">
```

When I receive the event and test the types:

```
eventReceive: function(event){

   alert(typeof event.some_text);// RETURNS STRING
   alert(typeof event.some_ID_number_as_string);// RETURNS NUMBER

}
```

I want to keep the passed data '**some_ID_number_as_string**' in a **string** format - for concatenation and string comparisons.

Why/where is this being being converted to a number - and - how do I prevent this from being converted to a number?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe if you set a breakpoint on this code in your browser's developer you should get a full trace of how you got to that point, with all the functions called beforehand. Certainly in Chrome you can do that. That might give you a clue as to possible places where a conversion is taking place. Presumably if you just convert it back to a string, you lose some fidelity (e.g. leading zeroes)? Or, could you convert whatever you want to compare it to into a number too, and then compare those? The result should be the same.

Comment: Thanks very much ADyson. Yes - I can convert and make comparisons. It is not that critical that it remains a number. It is just an ID number from a table. It is fine as a string, I expected it to stay that way. It is just strange to me that I am passing a string as data to fullcalendar and it automatically converts it to s number? I wasn't expecting this and was making a === comparison that threw an error. I just don't want unexpected things to happen and if I am making some sort of error I want to know.... can't find anything in the docs and suspect it is something with moment js?

Comment: I doubt it's in momentJS, because that's only comes into play for date fields. Probably fullCalendar is parsing the string and determining whether it's numeric, and then converting it on that basis. _Why_ it does that, I don't know. Like I said you'd need to trace it in the source. If you believe it to be a bug, you could raise that (via GitHub as a I understand)